# Finitely Generated Subset

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $L\subset\mathbb{Z}^n$ be a subset closed under addition and subtraction. Can we show that $L$ is generated by at most $n$ elements?

Comment: $L\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} \mathbb{Q}$ is a vector subspace of $\mathbb{Q}^n$, hence is generated by at most $n$ elements.

Comment: $L$ is also generated by $L$ itself. Maybe you mean to ask: can we show that $L$ is generated by a subset of it that has a cardinality that does not exceed $n$?